# Cross Object validation rules

Tags: validation-rule

I am newbie who trying to write her first validation rule. However, I am stuck and hoping to get some help.
I need to write a validation rule to prevent user from selecting Project (custom object) Status of "Hibernation" without selecting 2 users (custom object) with the hibernation status "hibernation admin"
Here is what i have so far but it gave me a syntax error.

```
AND (
    DatasiteOne_Project__c.Hibernation_status__c, “Hibernation Admin” <2,
    ISPICKVAL( Status, "Hibernation"),  
)
```

Comment: I was about to answer this re the syntax error, but looking at it I'm not sure a validation rule alone will cut it. I think if you need to see how many child records have a certain status, you'll need to combine it with perhaps a rollup summary (if possible) or failing that either trigger/flow....assuming i've understood correctly.